# Adding Read More to Custom excerpts

Tags: functions, excerpt

I've added the following code to my functions.php:

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
    global $post;
    return '<strong><a class="moretag" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">... Read More</a></strong>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

This adds a read more link to excerpts that have been automatically generated, i.e. an author hasn't specified anything in the excerpt field when posting an article.

So far so good.

However I would also like this to appear when something has been specified in this box, currently it only displays in the first instance.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show your custom excerpt more text when a post has a manual excerpt, you can filter the excerpt using the `get_the_excerpt` filter, use `has_excerpt()` (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_excerpt) to determine whether the post has a manual excerpt or not, and append the output of your already-existing custom excerpt more function to the excerpt if not. Here's some code that I tested with your custom excerpt more function above, which does the trick:

```
function excerpt_more_for_manual_excerpts( $excerpt ) {
    global $post;

    if ( has_excerpt( $post->ID ) ) {
        $excerpt .= new_excerpt_more( '' );
    }

    return $excerpt;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'excerpt_more_for_manual_excerpts' );
```

Comment: Still works in 2022!  Just remember to implement the `new_excerpt_more()` or inline replace with whatever you need